# how prevent the parent click event on change a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox inside a parent container which has a click event, whenever I try to click the checkbox parent click works first and following by the change event, I am using `e.stopPropagation();` on both the parent and child events, but still, it's not working

```
// make the .parent react
 function grandParent(){
    alert('Grand Parent: You hit me, my child or my grand child, now deal with me!');
}

// make the .parent react
$('.parent').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
    alert('Parent : Don\'t you dare hitting me or my child, again!');
});

// make the child cry, when we hit him.
$('.child').on('click', function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
 alert('Child : waaaaaa waaaa waa huh huh waaa waaaa!');
});

$('.hello').on('change', function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
 alert('checkbox clicked');
});
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qkLak5e2/1/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to bind the `click` event on the checkbox and not the `change` event: http://jsfiddle.net/ohc8jt6w/

Answer (score 1):

Sequence of the event matters , where the click event occurs first and Change event the next ,So in your case you need to change the type of event handling to `Click` **[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/899xkqc6/)** to see the sequence / priority of events happening after clicking on check box

```
$('.hello').on('click change', function(e){
e.stopPropagation(); 
 alert('checkbox '+e.type);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens because `e.stopPropagation();` is on `change` event and `.child` has click event. You can do this like in @rikpg example, but if you need change event, you should just add new one `click event` to checkbox that only has `stopPropagation`

http://jsfiddle.net/wppv2152/2/